# If we send mail from php script to gmail or another mail application is there any filters like spam and any other procedures

Tags: php, mysql

I having too doubt on mailing from php script to other mail applications. I am using Xammp server 1.7.7 php version 5.3.8. and what are the way for mailing from php like php core mail(), phpmailer(), smtp. and what is the use of mime in header of php mail().

Comment: I'm completely confused about what you're trying to ask. Please try to formulate a more coherent question.

Comment: hmm.. just you understand how i confused. ok simply i ask that how to send mail from php script to other mail(gmail,hmail..)

Comment: and i have to seen some more tutorials but i could't understood that all. So may you help by simple way

Answer (score 1):

1. > what are the way for mailing from php like php core mail(), phpmailer(), smtp.

   [SMTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_Mail_Transfer_Protocol) is the primary protocol, or 'language', used by computers that wish to transmit email.  It does not in any way define the contents of the email itself, except insofar as SMTP servers may add headers to the top of each email.

   The manual entry for PHP's [`mail()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) function notes:

   > If intending to send HTML or otherwise Complex mails, it is recommended to use the PEAR package [» PEAR::Mail_Mime](http://pear.php.net/package/Mail_Mime).

   and:

   > It is worth noting that the **mail()** function is not suitable for larger volumes of email in a loop. This function opens and closes an SMTP socket for each email, which is not very efficient.
   >
   > For the sending of large amounts of email, see the [» PEAR::Mail](http://pear.php.net/package/Mail), and [» PEAR::Mail_Queue](http://pear.php.net/package/Mail_Queue) packages.
2. > what is the use of mime in header of php mail()

   [MIME](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME) is the primary means of encoding emails that use non-ASCII characters, or which contain attachments/multiple parts.  Emails encoded using MIME indicate this fact in their headers.

   Whilst `mail()` does not provide any specific tools for sending MIME emails, one *could* encode an email's content accordingly and provide it to `mail()` (along with appropriate MIME headers) for onward transmission.  Since there are tools that make this task much easier, I wouldn't recommend trying this approach except as an academic exercise.

The title of your question asks:

> is there any filters like spam and any other procedures

Spam filtering, which takes place on the recipient's email system, looks at various aspects of the email to make a guess over whether the email is spam or not.  What it actually looks for will vary from system to system, but the sorts of things that may be considered include:

- was the email transmitted by a host (on a network) that has been seen transmitting spam before?
- has the operator of the claimed sender's domain indicated the systems which may transmit mail on their behalf (e.g. using [SPF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sender_Policy_Framework)) and/or specified keys by which their emails must be signed (e.g. using [ADSP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Author_Domain_Signing_Practices))?
- is the email similar to other known spam messages, which might include looking for (the absence of) certain headers (such as `User-Agent`, which identifies the software that generated the email—one could spoof this header so that generated email would appear to have been generated by some other software package)?

The means by which you generate email in PHP has very little impact on such factors: it's probably best to concentrate on sending emails first and then worry about making adjustments if you find that spam filters are frequently flagging your messages.

Comment: Dear sir first i thanks and response to you to care for me. thanks lot lord.